# PnP PowerShell command for Reuse Term

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell, managed-metadata-service

Is anybody know what is the PnP PowerShell command for **Reuse Term** and **Pin Term** functionalities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this using only PnP commands. But you can do it by dropping down to a little bit of CSOM.

First, fetch your source term and your destination term.

```
$pinnedTerm = Get-PnPTaxonomyItem -TermPath "Conglomo|Departments|Research and Development"
$sourceTermSet = Get-PnPTaxonomyItem -TermPath "Conglomo|Sitemap|Department Sites"
```

Then, call the one of the CSOM methods to reuse.

```
# option 1: reuse
$sourceTermSet.ReuseTerm($pinnedTerm, $true)

# option 2: reuse with pinning
$sourceTermSet.ReuseTermWithPinning($pinnedTerm)
```

Then you need to load and execute.

```
(Get-PnPContext).Load($pinnedTerm)
Invoke-PnPQuery
```

Comment: Thanks Derek. I will try your approach and let you know if any questions.

Answer (score 0):

## option 1: reuse

$sourceTermSet.ReuseTerm($pinnedTerm, $true)

## option 2: reuse with pinning

$sourceTermSet.ReuseTermWithPinning($pinnedTerm)

## The above statements are INCORRECT - see below for working code:

**#PIN TERM WITH CHILDREN - Unable to do it in PnP Schema (supported by the schema but NOT by the engine)!!**
`$termStore = Get-PnPSiteCollectionTermStore`

`$pinnedTerm = Get-PnPTaxonomyItem -TermPath "$($localTaxonomySession)|Site Navigation"`
`$sourceTermSetDirectorates = Get-PnPTaxonomyItem -TermPath "National Trust|Site Navigation|Directorates"`

`$pinnedTerm.ReuseTermWithPinning($sourceTermSetDirectorates )`

`(Get-PnPContext).Load($pinnedTerm)`
`Invoke-PnPQuery`

`$termStore.CommitAll()`    # Added this to ensure persistance